# Why "NETWORK SERVICE" doesn't have permission on "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" by default?

Tags: asp.net, security, windows-server-2008, file-permissions

I grant permission to `NETWORK SERVICE` manually to have access to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` so `ASP.NET` can do something like reading and writing local files.

Is there a security reason this permission has not been granted by default ?

Comment: @RandomNoob: Server 2008 enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the principle of [defence in depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_in_depth) - not giving permissions unless explicitly granted.

Such defaults make for a more secure IIS and operating system.

Several years ago Microsoft went through a very large push towards securing windows by default - this setting is part of that push.

Comment: Curious, how exactly does deference-in-depth relate to default-deny behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Per this article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx):

The Network Service account has Read and Execute permissions on the IIS server root folder by default. The IIS server root folder is named Wwwroot. This means that an ASP.NET application deployed inside the root folder already has Read and Execute permissions to its application folders. However, if your ASP.NET application needs to use files or folders in other locations, you must specifically enable access.

Comment: Written on August 2005 applying to .NET 2.0 and Windows Server 2003.

Comment: See my comment on the original question, he didn't specify what OS he is using, he could be using .NET 2.0 and Win2k3, a lot of people still do.

Comment: Fair enough, he specified later - not certain if the behavior is different in Win2k8, can't find a definite resource.

Answer (score 1):

usually on the web server just few folders are allowed to write to avoid potential security holes.